# JAVA String replaceAll hashtag contents

Tags: java, hashtag, replaceall

I'm using the below code as a test for later when using the Twitter API.

When I fetch tweets from my stream and store them in mySQL, how do I remove the hashtags along with any trailing characters? (basically omitting everything inside the hashtag)

I am able to use replaceAll and pass the "#" and "," values and replace them with "". It works and the output is below the code, but how would I use to replaceAll of the contents of the hashtag including the "not" "#not"?

```
public class replaceAllTest {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        String sampleString = "This game was amazing, #not";

        System.out.println("Before: " + sampleString);

        sampleString = sampleString.replaceAll("#", "");
        sampleString = sampleString.replaceAll(",", "");

        System.out.println("After: " + sampleString);
    }

}
```

The output from the above code:

```
Before: This game was amazing, #not
After: This game was amazing not
```

Expected output from the above code:

```
Before: This game was amazing, #not
After: This game was amazing
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks Z19

Comment: I suggest you check some introduction tutorial on regular expressions. `(,?\s*#[^\s]+)+`  http://www.rexfiddle.net/r3hU8jT

Comment: Thank you, collectively the three of you have helped me. I appreciate you quick responses :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use regex

```
sampleString = sampleString.replaceAll("#[A-Za-z]+","");
```

If you are expecting lone hashtags not followed by text, use `"#[A-Za-z]*"`

The comment on your question addresses hashtags that are followed by more than just alpha characters - `"#[^\\s]+` where `[^\\s]` means anything not whitespace.

Comment: @Z19 You will actually want to use his second suggestion, the `#[^\s]+`. Also, take thirty minutes to read about [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax). It is one of the most useful things you can know.

Comment: I have a "Invalid escape sequence" error on ("#[^\s]+","");

Comment: @Z19 fixed. Needed to escape the escape for java string

Answer (score 1):

I would go for some like

```
sampleString = sampleString.replaceAll(",\s+#[A-Za-z]+", "");
```

try using this website to help http://regexpal.com/

Comment: You helped me. Thank you :)